# How to run two loop simeltanously in one loop in python

Tags: python

Is there any way available to put two loops in one? I have:

```
for getFeature in layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures():
    for setFeature in layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures():
```

I want to run `layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures()` and `layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()` under one loop. How can I do this?

I don't want to nest them, I want to get both loop columns at a time.

Comment: Are you looking for this one? `for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b): print a, b`

Comment: Exactly, post the answer my boy

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan `zip` does *not* provide the behavior you describe in the question. `zip` matches elements up by index. Your loop creates all possible combinations.

Comment: what i said in question? i want to run two loop in one loop in nesting behaviour

Comment: @jpmc26 zip doing this job

Comment: You should provide an example of what you want. Your requirement of _nested_ is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b): 
    print a, b
```

Comment: so zip will run both loop simeltanously ? itertools.product run nested ?

Comment: Yeah. Read the document. You will understand.

Comment: The two collections must have the same size or else the looping will stop as soon as the shortest is finished. See [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Answer (score 3):

`zip_longest` will iterate until all lists are consumed.  For `zip` the results are truncated to the shortest iterator.

```
from itertools import zip_longest    

for get_feature, set_feature in zip_longest(layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures(), layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()):
    print(get_feature, set_feature)
```

Here's an example of both `zip` and `zip_longest` output:

DummyObject Setup code:

```
class DummyObject:
    def __init__(self, reversed=False, length=10):
        self.reversed = reversed
        self.length = length

    def getFeatures(self):
        if self.reversed:
            g = reversed(range(self.length))
        else:
            g = range(self.length)
        return g

layerNameValueGetObj = DummyObject(False, length=10)
layerNameValueSetObj = DummyObject(True, length=15)
```

Run with `zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest    

for get_feature, set_feature in zip_longest(layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures(), layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()):
    print(get_feature, set_feature)
```

zip_longest result:

```
0 14
1 13
2 12
3 11
4 10
5 9
6 8
7 7
8 6
9 5
None 4
None 3
None 2
None 1
None 0
```

Run with `zip`:

```
for get_feature, set_feature in zip(layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures(), layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()):
        print(get_feature, set_feature)
```

zip result:

```
0 14
1 13
2 12
3 11
4 10
5 9
6 8
7 7
8 6
9 5
```

So in this case where layerNameValueGetObj has 10 features and layerNameValueSetObj has 15 features, with `zip` only a total of 10 features will be processed with the remaining 5 layerNameValueSetObj features truncated.

With `zip_longest`, the shorter iterator will return `None` where no elements exist. (as seen above)

Comment: what do u mean by "truncated to the shortest"

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.product` exists for exactly this purpose

```
import itertools

for getFeature, setFeature in itertools.product(layerNameValueGetObj.getFeatures(), layerNameValueSetObj.getFeatures()):
    # dostuff
```

Comment: no this is not working correctly it working in nesting behviour i dont want to nest

Comment: 0
0,
1
0,
2
0,
3
0,
4
0,

Comment: I want to run both loop simultaneously